# DynamoDB - scan one-by-one (like a JDBC cursor)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to get ANY row in my DynamoDB table, but the table could be very big. I don't want to have the DB server return all rows to me and then I just get the first item in the set.

With JDBC I'd use a cursor which is just a "pointer" to  row in the database. In DynamoDB I've been looking at the `scan()` operation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) but there are so many similar methods, and they vary between versions, and parameters that don't do what I was expecting that I'm really confused. I really don't want to submit JSON queries if there is a simple programmatic statement to do it.

What method should I be looking for to just get items one-by-one from client to server, rather than the server batching them up and returning multiple?

### My attempt:

`new DynamoDB(
                    AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1.name())
                        .build())
                .getTable("my_large_table")
                // MaxResultSize just blindly returns rows, not matching rows. Since we have no filter criteria this is fine.
                .scan(new ScanSpec().withMaxResultSize(1).withConsistentRead(true))
                .firstPage()
                .getLowLevelResult()
                .getScanResult()
                .getItems();`

### Version info

For now I'm using these but if it's changed in later versions I'd like to know the solution that minimizes future migration pain:

`<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.127</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.127</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.127</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-Limit) Scan argument.

By default Scan will evaluate every item in a table. Using the limit operator will set "the maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching items)".

So if you Scan a table with no filters, and Limit set to 1, you will always get one item returned (assuming there is at least one item).